# Problema com $_SESSION em sistema de login, $_SESSION encerra sozinha

Tags: php, session, login, cookies

Meu sistema de login não está funcionando...

No meu projeto tenho um arquivo chamado **cabecalho.php**

```
<?php
ob_start(); //abrir sessao
session_start();//iniciar sessao
error_reporting(0); //ignorar alguns erros

    include("Pdo/conexao.php"); //conexao com banco de dados
    include("includes/logout.php"); //arquivo pra delogar usuario
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> ...
```

Este **cabecalho.php** esta linkado por include em todas as paginas...

O meu menu contém no canto superior direito um botom pra abrir o form login.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o **menuprincipal.php** tem o seguinte código:

```
<?php

            if(isset($_GET['acao'])){

              if(isset($POST['logar'])){

                $acao = $_GET['acao'];

                if($acao=='negado'){
                  header("Location: login.php?acao=acessonegado");
                }
              }
            }
            //se EXISTIR usuario e senha logados
            if(isset($_SESSION['USUARIOCFSITE']) && (isset($_SESSION['SENHACFSITE']))){

              include 'includes/usuariologado.php';              
            }else{

              if(isset($_POST['logar'])){

                $usuario = trim(strip_tags($_POST['usuario']));
                $senha = trim(strip_tags($_POST['senha']));

                if ($usuario == "admin" and $senha == "123123") {

                  //recuperar o POST (oq usuario digitou)
                  $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
                  $senha = $_POST['senha'];
                  $_SESSION['USUARIOCFSITE'] = $usuario;
                  $_SESSION['SENHACFSITE'] = $senha;

                  include 'includes/usuariologado.php';

                }else{
                  include 'includes/usuariodesconectado.php';
                }

              }else{
                include 'includes/usuariodesconectado.php';
              }
            }

            ?>
```

Minha lógica é: se exitir sessão aberta de usuário, o sistema da um include no arquivo que contem perfil do usuário. Caso não exista a sessão ele da um include no arquivo que tem form de login.

Até então o login funciona! Porém, ao acessar outra página, o usuário é deslogado.
É como se a sessão se encerrasse.

Mas sendo que meu **logout.php** está sobre a condição de um request!

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['sair'])) {
        session_destroy();
        session_unset( $_SESSION['USUARIOCFSITE'] );
        session_unset( $_SESSION['SENHACFSITE'] );
        header("Location: login.php?acao=logout");
    }   
?>
```

Meus caros, sou iniciante e confesso que li muito antes de perguntar, mas me encontro com dificuldades de entender este processo. Conto com a colaboração de vocês.

P.S. Uma observação importante é que... este erro acontece somente com o projeto que está hospedado na web, sendo que em LOCALHOST funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Abra session_start(); em todos os arquivos que ver verificar a existencia de sessões, acho que é isso, boa sorte!

Comment: Qual serviço de hospedagem utiliza?
Se estiver por exemplo em um load balance da amazon, [tem umas regrinhas do servidor que é necessário configurar](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se não me engano, em todas páginas que for conferir a sessão, tem que ser usada
uma `session_start()` novamente, senão é como se estivesse fechada.

Para confirmar minha dica, de um `var_dump($_SESSION)` antes e um depois do `session_start()`, vai ver que o primeiro vai dar **null**.

Comment: Eu uso session_start() no arquivo cabecalho.php assim toda pagina tem este comando, usei o var_dump($_SESSION), e tá ok. Ele mostra os dados de login, mas a session recebe null quando a page atualiza.

Comment: Você está trabalhando localmente com xampp por exemplo? recomendo voce dar uma procurada no seu arquivo php.ini por tudo relacionado a sesion como session.cookie_lifetime=0, ou antes disso, passa um debug no seu php desde a primeira linha do seu código, ou a sua sessao está configurada pra durar muito pouco tempo, ou você esqueceu em algum lugar um session_destroy()

Comment: Eu uso Wamp Server, e em LocalHost não tenho estes problemas.
O erro acontece no site online, seria algum problema do provedor de hospedagem ? Acho que não...

Aqui neste fórum pode se disponibilizar contatos? Gostaria de deixar meu whatsapp aqui.

Answer (score 0):

***"P.S. Uma observação importante é que... este erro acontece somente com o projeto que está hospedado na web, sendo que em LOCALHOST funciona perfeitamente."***

O problema está na configuração do arquivo `PHP.ini` que fica na raiz do servidor.
Este arquivo tem que ser configurado com os padrões da hospedagem.
Um exemplo da locaweb para ambiente linux:

```
session.save_path = "/home/SEU_LOGIN_FTP/tmp"
```

No caso da locaweb a area *"SEU_LOGIN_FTP"* tem que ser alterada com o login do FTP para funcionar corretamente. Verifique a configuração do seu servidor de hospedagem.

[veja mais aqui](https://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Session_em_PHP)